# Spring WS managing Custom FAult

Tags: spring-ws

I'm handling my custom soap fault using the recipe:
http://www.stevideter.com/2009/02/18/of-exceptionresolvers-and-xmlbeans/

The part of the code which transforms (using *identity transformation* - no XSLT) XML to soap fault detail is:

```
protected void customizeFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex, SoapFault soapFault) {
  Transformer trn = null;
  Result result = null;
  SoapFaultDetail faultDetail = null;
  try {
    trn = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    faultDetail = soapFault.addFaultDetail();

    // detail contains org.apache.xmlbeans marshalled xml
    StreamSource detail = ...
    result = faultDetail.getResult();
    trn.transform(detail, result); 
  ...
}
```

When I test the output with SoapUI, I'm getting schema validation errors, because the response is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en">it.fault.InputFault</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <inputFault xmlns="http://fault.my.it">
          <code>ERR-INPUT 003</code>
          <message>Dati in input non completi</message>
        </inputFault>
      </detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My XSD has no `elementFormDefault` so it is `unqualified` and the response should look like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en">it.fault.InputFault</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <inputFault xmlns="http://fault.my.it">
          <code xmlns="">ERR-INPUT 003</code>
          <message xmlns="">Dati in input non completi</message>
        </inputFault>
      </detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The result should be the same as xmlnbeans marshalled object and it should contain `xmlns=""`.

Can someone help me to understand why the transformation removed the `xmlns` declarations?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you really get this message from a web service? This is not well-formed XML. There's `<code>` start tag and `</codice>` end tag...

Comment: @Grzegorz Grzybek  YES.. Have you ever encountered it??

Comment: I've pasted your (first) XML and SOAP UI said it's OK...

Comment: @Grzegorz Grzybek  can you Help me?

Comment: You also have `<message xmlns=">` instead of `<message xmlns="">` (two double quotes)

Comment: @Grzegorz Grzybek HUmmm... the second is the response that I would obtain...But I really don't understand why it didn'it throws correct, because a have follow the recipe of:
http://www.stevideter.com/2009/02/18/of-exceptionresolvers-and-xmlbeans/

Comment: I can't quite understand - do you want to get `xmlns=""` in `<code>` and `<message>` elements (as in the recipe) or not? You're transforming `detail` element - how does it look like? And, what's most important, what your WSDL looks like (WSDL tells Soap UI how to validate the message).

Comment: @Grzegorz Grzybek Yes I would like obtain xmlns="" in <code> and <message> elements (as in the recipe). In fact my doubt is what doing the method  trn.transform(detail, result); , cause in detail string an obtain the correct string object <inputFault xmlns="http://fault.my.it">
           <code xmlns="">ERR-INPUT 003</code>
           <message xmlns="">Dati in input non completi</message>
        </inputFault>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6610/discussion-between-grzegorz-grzybek-and-bomberlatinos9)

Comment: @Grzegorz Grzybek if i remove xalan.jar from endorsed, the application can't read some xml files.. :(

Comment: have you replaced it with xalan-2.7.1.jar or just removed?

Comment: I have removed it ... IT' is not correct??

Comment: I have removed it...because i have thougth that both jar could not lives together..

Comment: library of xalan 2.1.7 it is the right solution...

Comment: HI greg...are you here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO... Thanks to Grzegorz Grzybek I have found that xalan.jar, didn't work so well, if you have it on the directory "endorsed" of Jboss 4.2 and you compile with java 1.5. The solution is to download xalan-2.7.1.jar and sostituite it with xalan all should work fine to have xmlns="" into the SoapREsponse like:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
     <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring xml:lang="en">it.my.fault.InputFault</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <inputFault xmlns="http://my.it/version-1-0-0">
           <codice xmlns="">ERR-INPUT 003</codice>
           <messaggio xmlns="">Dati in input non completi</messaggio>
        </inputFault>
     </detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```